# C++ stream insertion overloading error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having trouble with a basic stream insertion overload. The code is fairly self-explanatory:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class dictionary
{
public:
  using map_type = std::map<std::string, std::string>;
  using ostream_iterator_type = std::ostream_iterator<map_type::value_type>;

private:
  map_type inner;

public:
  dictionary() : inner()
  {
    inner["foo"] = "lorem";
    inner["baz"] = "ipsum";
  }

  void
  write(std::ostream& os)
  {
    os << "{\n";
    std::copy(std::begin(inner), std::end(inner), ostream_iterator_type(os, "\n"));
    os << "}";
  }
};

dictionary::ostream_iterator_type::ostream_type&
operator<<(dictionary::ostream_iterator_type::ostream_type& os,
           dictionary::map_type::value_type const& p)
{
  os << p.first << " => " << p.second;
  return os;
}
```

This code throws some huge template errors, claiming that there's no appropriate overload for `operator<<` with the two arguments that I've clearly defined. What obvious problem am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not [mcve]. Where's the invocation of the `operator <<`? Where (on which line) the error occurs? What is the error (copy-paste it **exactly**, without paraphrasing)? Are those nested types necessary to reproduce the error? If not, why did you include them in your _attempted_ [mcve]?

Comment: This is a well-formed question (aside from lack of complete error text). The down votes are rough. The first thing I've noticed is the lack of `<ostream>` and `<algorithm>` include. Also you seem to define `operator <<` only *after* it is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I've noticed is the lack of `<ostream>` and `<algorithm>` includes. Also you seem to define `operator <<` only after it is required. But the real problem is that you are trying to define `operator <<` taking `::std::pair` as second parameter outside of `std` namespace. You can fix it appropriately redefining it like this:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <algorithm>

class dictionary
{
public:
  using map_type = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

private:
  map_type inner;

public:
  dictionary() : inner()
  {
    inner["foo"] = "lorem";
    inner["baz"] = "ipsum";
  }

  void
  write(std::ostream& os);
};

namespace std
{
  std::ostream &
  operator <<(std::ostream & os, dictionary::map_type::const_reference & p)
  {
    os << p.first << " => " << p.second;
    return os;
  }
} // namespace std

void dictionary::
write(std::ostream& os)
{
  using ostream_iterator_type = std::ostream_iterator<map_type::value_type>;
  os << "{\n";
  std::copy(std::begin(inner), std::end(inner), ostream_iterator_type(os, "\n"));
  os << "}";
}
```

Comment: Oh god! Such a stupid mistake. Thanks for the help :)